# AHK script to open an Excel file does not work

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following code to open an Excel file:

```
F11::             


xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Dropbox\PROJECTEN\Continue\pi\personal_dashboard.xlsx")            
        xlApp := ""                                 
    return
```

When I run it however nothing opens. Any though on whether Im missing something?

Comment: I haven't messed around with opening files in AHK that much, but this might help https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/16544-autohotkey-rockshow-do-i-open-file-with-specific-program/ (could also be outdated since lua)

Answer (score 4):

Before opening a (new) COM object, you need to create it:

```
F11::
    xlApp := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")    ; create a (new) instance of Excel
    xlApp.Visible := true                         ; make Excel visible
    ; xlApp := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")  ; make Excel active   
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Dropbox\PROJECTEN\Continue\pi\personal_dashboard.xlsx")    
    xlApp := ""   ; clear the variable
return
```

See also https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/56987-com-object-reference-autohotkey-v11/page-4#entry381256

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file simply by doing

```
run "C:\Users\User\Dropbox\PROJECTEN\Continue\pi\personal_dashboard.xlsx"
```

It would be the same as typing "C:\users...\personal_dashboard.xlsx" into the run dialog. As long as you have Excel as the default program to open .xlsx files, then it should open without problems.

Comment: I think you forgot a comma?